# Programmatically convert SQLite to .sql

Tags: c#, mysql, database, sqlite

Alright, this will probably sound a bit silly.  The more I think about it, the sillier it sounds.

**Background**:
The company I'm working for hired a guy about a year ago to write some software for them.  This software (written in VB6) is for a drilling supplies manufacturer (sensors, bits, etc).  Anyway, the software is installed at a rig site, and provides a plethora of information (bit depth, rpms, etc).  Now, a reading is taken every 10 seconds, and saved to a file. (I was initially told a local SQL database, but that's proved incorrect.)  This file, which can apparently only be opened in SQLite Database Browser (opening it in any text editor results in looking at garbage, essentially).

**Move Forward**:
I was hired to write a program that takes the data that is saved, and create a daily report based upon it.  Initially, I was told that there was a MySQL database on the local machine that is storing the information.  However, I just recently found out that that is not the case.  It's stored in this file.  I can open the file in SQLite Database Browser, and export it as a .sql file, and that is all awesome and such.  Problem is, my employer wants this done programmatically.

**My Question**:
Is there a way to convert this SQLite file to .sql programmatically, or what is the best route to get this information uploaded into a local MySQL database?  Thank you for much for any assistance.

Comment: You don't need Mysql at all. Just do your report on said SQLite database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered just using a [the] SQLite data provider for .NET and opening and reading the data out that way?  You could easily read the data out of the SQLite database, and the write it into the MySQL database (using the appropriate MySQL data provider).

Here's the SQLite data provider I've used in the past: http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/  I'm not sure if there's something newer (or better).

Comment: The data isn't being stored in the SQLite database.  It's being stored in a file that is only readable by SQLite.  Would this make a difference?  Should I be able to still read the data and then upload the MySQL?

Comment: A file that is only readable by SQLite, but isn't SQLite?  I'm not familiar with anything like that, so I don't know.  What's the file extension, are you sure it's not an SQLite database (they are just single files).

Comment: SQLite is a *flat file database* it is designed to reside in a single file. The content is indeed binary, not textual so no text editor can read it just like not text editor can read internal MySQL files. Text editors can read the exported SQL commands (that's an *.sql file).

Comment: Microsoft Access *.mdb files are another example of *flat file databases*, there were many examples in the past, SQLite and MSAccess are the most prominent current *flat file databases*. They were not designed for the same level of concurrency as *database servers* - they can handle concurrency without turning the file into garbage but AFAIK they were not designed for high-demand concurrency.

Comment: Between this answer, and what @banging said above, I actually just changed my initial connections from MySQL to SQLite, and everything worked out.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQLite Manager application you have to make an *.sql file dump of the data in the SQLite database. Import the resulting *.sql file into a MySQL database.

Write a C# script that will use this code:

```
sqlite_db_handler.query('SELECT * FROM dbname.sqlite_master WHERE type='table'');
```

To get a list of all the tables in the SQLite database.

Iterate over each of these tables and use this code:

```
sqlite_db_handler.query('SELECT * FROM '+table_name);
```

Iterate over each of the resulting rows using this code:

```
mysql_db_handler.query('REPLACE INTO '+table_name+' VALUES('+row.join("','")+')');
```

Done!

P.S.: It's pseudo-code I'm not a C# developer.